# C# Wrap array initialization with AsParallel - Expression Trees

Tags: c#, expression, expression-trees

How can I wrap NewArrayExpression with ParallelEnumerable.AsParallel ?

for example I have Expression what represent next code:

```
var data = new int {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

the result what I want to get:

```
var data = new int {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}.AsParallel();
```

I try use ExpressionVisitor and VisitNewArray method:

```
    protected override Expression VisitNewArray(NewArrayExpression node)
    {

            var source = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(MethodCallExpression)), "source");

            var asParallel =
                Expression.Call(
                    typeof(ParallelEnumerable),
                    nameof(ParallelEnumerable.AsParallel),
                    new[] { typeof(ParallelQuery<MethodCallExpression>) },
                    source
                );

            return ***???***
    }
```

But don't known how to right "wrap" **node.Expressions** this **Expression.Call**

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing so will change the expression type form `T[]` to `ParallelQuery<T>` which may cause issues.

But answering your concrete question. Let rewrite your example

```
var data = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}.AsParallel();
```

as follows

```
var newArray = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var data = newArray.AsParallel();
```

Now taking into account that `AsParallel` is generic static extension method, the actual call after removing the compiler sugar is

```
var data = ParallelEnumerable.AsParallel<int>(newArray);
```

In other words, calling the generic static method passing array element type as generic type argument and the `new` array expression as argument. e.g.

```
protected override Expression VisitNewArray(NewArrayExpression node)
{
    var asParallel = Expression.Call(
        typeof(ParallelEnumerable),
        nameof(ParallelEnumerable.AsParallel),
        new [] { node.Type.GetElementType() },
        node
    );
    return asParallel;
}
```